# Problem with Viber - "Share screen" not working

Tags: kubuntu, kde, plasma, sharing, viber

I'm having this issue for a while and haven't been able to find the culprit of it or any information on internet.

Basically when I'm on a Viber call and click "share screen", Viber minimizes, but doesn't give me the menu where I should choose which desktop to share. I'm using flatpak version of Viber but tried downloading it from the official website as .deb package, but it was the same thing.

I was initially experiencing this on Kubuntu 19.10, recently upgraded to 20.04 but unfortunately that didn't help.

The following JavaScript error is thrown when I try to share the screen:

```
qml: 21.193 JS: beginBrowserSelfVideoStreamRestart(streamActive = 1, streamType = 1, fromVoiceLib = 0) qml: 21.193 JS: n_tracks = 0, streamActiveEqual = false, streamTypeEqual = false qml: 21.194 JS: restartSelfVideoStream_() with selfVideoActive = 1, selfVideoType = 1 qml: 21.194 JS: Recreating stream qml: 21.195 JS: beginBrowserSelfVideoStreamRestart: restartSelfVideoStream_() failed with error: NotReadableError: Could not start video source
```

Can anyone please assist ? Anybody have experienced a similar issue ?